# Is it possible to start Android Service separately from the current application?

Tags: android, android-service

When I launch an application for the first time then service should be started - but separately from current application. So when I delete this application , service should still work. Is it possible in Android?

Comment: This type of question is asked so many times on Stackoverflow. Please consider that answers first. Still you cant find solutions then ask with appropriate explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, no, for obvious security reasons. If the user uninstalls ("delete") the application, *everything* is removed.

You are welcome to have two separate applications, though.